# How to shuffle two numpy arrays, so that record indices are stay aligned in both after shuffling?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shuffle

I have a 4D array and a 1D array:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randn(10, 1, 5, 5)    # num_records, depth, height, width
labels = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0])
```

I want to shuffle the data and labels by `num_records` to get `labels` in a random order.

I know that one could use `shuffle` function: `np.random.shuffle(data)`. But I don't know how to persist the relation between `data` and `labels` after shuffling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shuffles both arrays together:

```py
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randn(10, 1, 5, 5)    # num_records, depth, height, width
labels = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0])

# shuffle indices
idx = np.random.permutation(range(len(labels)))

# shuffle together
data, labels = data[idx,:,:,:], labels[idx]
```

Comment: You do not need trailing colons in numpy. `data, labels = data[idx], labels[idx]` will do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

```
import sklearn.utils as sku
array1_shuffled, array2_shuffled = sku.shuffle(array1, array2)
```

https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-shuffle-two-numpy-arrays-in-unision-in-python